# Как получить значение i-того элемента input?

Tags: jquery

На странице есть два одинаковых поля input

Значение первого можно получить

```
$("input[class='input-text qty text']").val();
```

как получить значение только второго?
Если я пишу с индексом

```
$("input[class='input-text qty text']").val(1);
```

то получаю объект, а как получить значение?

понимаю что это азы, но все таки...

Comment: у вас памяти нет ? вы же точно такой-же вопрос задавали вчера.

или вы действительно не можете догадаться, что чтобы получить значение i-того элемента надо получить i-й элемент из выборки, а потом его значение ?

Comment: )))) jquery лес дремучий, вот и разбираюсь на ходу. Понятие есть, практики маловато, но если вы присмотритесь к вопросу то увидите разницу что прошлый пост был по  

$('td.product-price').eq(i).text()

С  $("input[class='input-text qty text']").val(); такое не прокатывает. Когда консоль пишет error, а мануалы не ясны, приходится задавать такие вопросы. Не будьте так строги, еще не привык к синтаксису языка

Comment: вот у вас есть десять коробок вам надо посмотреть что во второй. вы умеете взять n-ю коробку, ваши действия ? **синтаксис тут не причём**

Comment: Давайте тогда посмотрим на ситуацию с моей стороны. 
Есть две кучи коробок. Допустим что подойдя к той куче что справа я научился брать n-ю коробку и смотреть значение внутри.
Но если по этому же принципу я подхожу к коробкам что слева, взяв  n-ю коробку и заглянув что внутри я получаю:
{
Object[input.input-text значение свойства = "1" значение атрибута = "3"]
  
 
0
 input.input-text значение свойства = "1" значение атрибута = "3"
 
context
 Document /cart/
}
 
Я ж говорю что пока не селен в синтаксисе вот и все

Comment: я почему-то не вижу в вашем коде .eq() описанное в ответе к предыдущему вопросу. вы попытались посмотреть во все коробки сразу. но умный jquery вам подсунул первую коробку, а если бы вы озаботились читать документацию вместо того чтобы прогать методом тыка, вы бы узнали, что аргументом метода val является значение которое вы хотите **передать** объекту.

Comment: Синтаксис не причем-согласен. Просто я его еще не освоил

    Если легко - значит освоил. Если тяжело - значит еще нет.

Comment: Такой листинг берет нужные коробки и их значения

    var getvalue3 = $("input[class='input-text qty text']");
var result1 = $(getvalue3[i]).val()

Comment: это неправильно, потому что вы зачем-то много раз делаете jQuery объект, для того чтобы взять конкретный объект нужно использовать eq.

    var result1 = getvalue3.eq(i).val();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь фильтром **[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** (отсчет с 0)

```
var num = 2; //для примера

//Выведет в консоль значение второго input с искомым классом
console.log($("input[class='input-text qty text']").eq(num - 1).val());
```

**Поясняющее обновление:**
**Два примера:**
1) $('.box').eq(1).val();
2) $('.box').eq(1).val('apple');

**Расшифровка:**
1) Куча коробок::Взять вторую::Заглянуть внутрь
2) Куча коробок::Взять вторую::Заглянуть внутрь и положить туда яблоко

Пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec5eu/)**

Answer (score -1):

[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/V8Csm/1/)

Comment: Спасибо! Коротко и доходчиво

Comment: и неправильно

Comment: почему не правильно?

Comment: потому-что вы вместо встроенной функции какой-то лисопед изобретаете. и я думаю, создаете jQuery объект из dom больше раз чем надо. 
так-то конечно можно и перебором :)